# Django update the row if its existing

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model say,

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    x = models.CharFeild(max_length=100)
    y = model.IntegerFeild(default=1)
```

and another model is,

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
        a = models.CharFeild(max_length=100)
        abc = model.ForeignKey(ABC, db_index=True)
```

and my existing database looks like,

```
ABC
id x  y
1  a  10
2  b  20
3  c  30
.   .  .
.   .   .

XYZ
id  a  abc_id
1   x  1
2   y  2
3   z  3
.   .  . 
.   .  .
```

So now I want to update the field if its exist in model XYZ i.e., change column 'a' value where abc_id=1 or 2 or 3, and if that abc_id doesn't exist create a new row.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`update_or_create()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method of QuerySet

```
new_value = {"a": "new value"}

XYZ.objects.update_or_create(abc_id=1,defaults=new_value)
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if it's possible to add a ***LOGICAL OR*** condtion with the **`update_or_create()`** method

---

**Update**
This can be also done by,

```
defaults = {"a": "new value"}
try:
    obj = XYZ.objects.get(abc_id=1)
    for key, value in defaults.items():
        setattr(obj, key, value)
    obj.save()
except XYZ.DoesNotExist:
    new_values = {"abc_id": 1}
    new_values.update(defaults)
    obj = XYZ(**new_values)
    obj.save()
```

Comment: so its like update_or_create takes two argument the one we need to update in a dict and the one on the row id should id update so for that we passed abc_id=1, right ?

Comment: It's not **two** arguments...it's ***one or more arguments***

Comment: So here abc_id = 1 exists then update the row with the new value else create the new row with new value. @JPG